# Filter function to create new dataframe from existing data

Tags: r, filter

I have the dataframe (Cumulative_COVID):

```
 Code   Country       Date     Continent NewCases NewDeaths
1  ARG Argentina 2020-03-04 South America        1         0
2  ARG Argentina 2020-03-06 South America        1         0
3  ARG Argentina 2020-03-07 South America        6         0
4  ARG Argentina 2020-03-08 South America        1         1
5  ARG Argentina 2020-03-09 South America        3         0
6  ARG Argentina 2020-03-11 South America        7         0
  Recovered NewTests Population    GDP GDPCapita Month Week CumCases
1         0        0   44494502 637486     14400     3   10        1
2         0        0   44494502 637486     14400     3   10        2
3         0        0   44494502 637486     14400     3   10        8
4         0        0   44494502 637486     14400     3   10        9
5         0        0   44494502 637486     14400     3   10       12
6         0        0   44494502 637486     14400     3   11       19
  CumDeaths CumRecovered CumTests Active Fatility_Rate
1         0            0        0      1    0.00000000
2         0            0        0      2    0.00000000
3         0            0        0      8    0.00000000
4         1            0        0      8    0.11111111
5         1            0        0     11    0.08333333
6         1            0        0     18    0.05263158
```

and I'm trying to create a new dataframe based only on the data on the 05/05/2020.

I believe using the filter function should achieve this

```
LAST_DAY_DATA <- filter(Cumulative_COVID$Date == "2020-05-05")
```

However, I keep receiving the error:

```
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

I'm a little confused as to why? Would greatly appreciate any advice

Comment: try doing `filter(Cumulative_COVID, Date == "2020-05-05")` or even `subset(Cumulative_COVID, Date == "2020-05-05")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply subset like this:

```
LAST_DAY_DATA <- Cumulative_COVID[Cumulative_COVID$Date == "2020-05-05",]
```

Comment: If the answer is helpful please consider accepting and/or upvoting it.